# Problem redirecting (301) w/ Nginx directives from old site subdirectory & wildcard address/args to new webroot

Tags: nginx, redirect, return, nginx-location

I had two old subdirectories that a site used to be located under, that are now all contained within the webroot.

I need to redirect all old link traffic to new location with **nginx directives**.

For example:

- `https://www.example.com/s/<wildcard>?<args>`
- `https://www.example.com/sc/<wildcard>?<args>`

Needs to redirect to the same site minus the subdirectory:

- `https://www.example.com/<wildcard>?<args>`

I've tried the following but it's only redirecting URL's without the wildcard and arguments. So this returns a `404`:

- `https://www.example.com/sc/index.php?rn=123`

but

- `https://www.example.com/sc` (or `/sc/`)

is stripped of the subdirectory correctly.

The two directives I've come up with are:

```
location ~* ^/sc/(.*) {
   return 301 /$1;
}

location ~* ^/s/(.*) {
   return 301 /$1;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) automatically handles arguments, and the [location `^~` operator](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is unambiguous.

For example:

```
location ^~ /sc/ {
    rewrite ^/sc(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}
location ^~ /s/ {
    rewrite ^/s(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}
```